# High ping without router

Tags: windows, ping

So, hello!
I am just a student, living in dorms and using internet provided by my school. For few months, everyone has got strange issue - we get really high ping - like 500~1000. What's strange? This ping is only on windows machines. I tested on pingtest to 1 place from my mac, got normal 30~40 ping, booted into my windows ( bootcamp ) and got 500 ping to exact same target. And 2nd thing - which i think is Really strange - if we plug router to same network cable, and then from router to our computers - we get normal ping!
So I am asking you, is there anything I can do to fix my ping? Assuming our network administrator is a jerk and dont want to do anything to fix this thing.

Comment: What do you mean by high ping?

Comment: @BenjiWeibe Ping times are measured in milliseconds, so high = high latency.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say it's something to do with DHCP, if going through a router fixes the issue. No idea why it would work fine on mac, though. (note: not a network expert)

Comment: -1 please add more detail to your question. a list of hardware used would help as well.

Comment: I have Mid 2012 Mac book pro - but that problem is not only for me - it is for everyone ( hundreds of PC's and laptops). OK, maybe it was a glitch, that i had ok ping when i tested at first. Now it is also high with mac. But the thing - 35 ping with router.